# Ternary relationship in sequelize - how should I do it

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I have this ternary relationship:
[image: photo]

I want to implement it into Sequelize but I couldn't find any docs on how to do it.

I was thinking about adding an ID field in ProfesoriClasa, then creating another pivot table, like this:
[image: photo]

would this approach be fine? Or is there any other way to implement that ternary relationship using Sequelize?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see why that is special.  It's extremely common to have a table with multiple foreign keys.  You just use a `references` section in each one.

Comment: @TimRoberts I don't know, I haven't stumbled across this type of relationship. The idea is that the relationship is of type many-to-many between all 3 tables, so that's what confuses me.

Comment: But it's not many-to-many.  ProfesoriClasa has three many-to-one relationships.  It's a simple foreign key, there just happens to be three of them.  Right?  It's EXACTLY like your `Nota` table, except you have 3 instead of 2.  Am I looking at the wrong tables?

Comment: I think this 3 way many-to-many is fine but you have extra connection between `Profesor` to `Clasa`. That could complicate things. Also on the first image, having only `id_clasa` as primary key, this seems weird. It suggests you don't need many-to-many between `Clasa` to `Profesor`.

Comment: @TimRoberts Nota was supposed to be a pivot table for a many-to-many relationship. :) I think I know how to do it now, though.

Comment: @Emma I didn't know (until you pointed it out) that for a many-to-many relationship the primary key should be composed of all the fields. I've just researched this topic after you pointed it out. Thanks.